# How to propably and securly validate CAPTCHA using PHP

Tags: php, validation, security, captcha

I was using Google reCAPTCHA and it was working very nice. but because of some issues I started to use php image CAPTCHA.
CAPTCHA image rendered correctly but I can't validate it correctly.

I use this code to generate CAPTCHA

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_text']))
{
unset($_SESSION['captcha_text']);
}

$permitted_chars = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
// ...
// code to generate CAPTCHA
// ...
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

then I show CAPTCHA using this code

```
<img src="CAPTCHA/captcha.php" alt="CAPTCHA" class="captcha-image"><i style="position: absolute;" class="refresh-captcha"></i><BR>
<input autocomplete="off" style="margin-top: 0.8rem;" type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha_challenge" pattern="[A-Z]{6}">
```

Now I validate CAPTCHA in another PHPfile using this code

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true);
if(isset($_POST['captcha_challenge']) && strtoupper($_POST['captcha_challenge']) == $_SESSION['captcha_text']) {
    echo '<p>You entered a correct Captcha.</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>You entered an incorrect Captcha.</p>';
}

$_SESSION['captcha_text'] = NULL;
unset($_SESSION['captcha_text']);
exit;
```

till now it worked correctly. I test it manually and it works.
But when I use some security scripts to test forms, I get spam.
why?? what I missed??
<--sorry for my bad English-->

Comment: where do you set `$_SESSION['captcha_text']` ? You might get spam if your captcha is simple for a computer to read (OCR).

Comment: Rather than try to reinvent the wheel, just save yourself the hassle and use Google reCaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK
After searching internet I decided to go back to Google reCaptcha and try to fix display issues that occure in my website with reCaptcha.
As [@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2292397/steve) said

> Rather than try to reinvent the wheel, just save yourself the hassle
>   and use Google reCaptcha.